# CSS - Number auto-increasing animation not work in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I am trying to implement an auto-increasing number animation by CSS following [this article](https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/).

It works well in my application when opening in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari, it always shows 0.

Do you have any idea about this problem? Here's the snippet:

```css
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

div {
  animation: counter 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  padding: 2rem;
}
div::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: There is no support in Firefox and Safari for [@property](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property) at the moment.

Comment: wow I don't know that, thank you